# Передача данных клиенту

Tags: jquery, json, php, ajax, javascript

**Как осуществляется передача данных клиенту от сервера?**

Например, ВКонтакте, когда запроса нет, а уведомление приходит о новом сообщении.
Или каждую секунду, например, отправляется запрос серверу проверить, не появилось ли новое сообщение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно через AJAX-запросы, но я не проверял, обычно именно так. В фейсбуке на AJAX, я проверял.
Есть ещё "технологии COMET" - образуют стримобразные потоки. Они куда лучше AJAX, но затратнее по коду, браузерам (надо же и старьё учить этому, а это очень сложно, если вообще возможно), простоте.

Comment: @TheDoctor, значит COMET это тот же AJAX, но с long polling.
А фейсбук проверяет через интервал наличие новой информации на сервере?

Comment: @Doofy, Нет, не AJAX, там другие технологии. Длинный запрос - одна из разновидностей (самая дебильная ИМХО).
Когда я проверял - да, он отправлял запрос где-то раз в 3 секунды на какой-то файл, возвращал JSON ответ - стандартная процедура.

Comment: @TheDoctor, что-то я не сообразил сразу открыть лог консоли при открытой страничке http://vk.com/im и посмотреть, какие запросы отправляются.
Работает всё через ajax (readyState 4), и проверяется новая инфа с интервалом от секунды до пяти секунд. Ну что ж, меня больше не мучает этот вопрос. :)

Comment: @Doofy, рад помочь :)  
Если сам собрался делать, то присмотрись всё же к стримам, вебсокетам, etc.